# MySQL Left join ruins result

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have field `date DATE` in table A and field `date INT` in table B. I am trying to select all rows from table A where date between today and last day of month and JOIN table B by date (sure I do conversion), but in result I only have 1 result row.

I have created SQLFiddle with my data and query, I it may help..
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e107d/1

Comment: You only have 1 row because you are using an aggregate function: `COUNT(o.id)`

Comment: I guessed that.. How can I resolve problem?

Comment: What do you want to count to be of? Possibly you can just add GROUP BY day before the HAVING clause

Comment: @Kickstart GROUP BY day is solution. Please post it as answer to make possible mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer rather than a comment

Issue appears to be that the query requires GROUP BY day being added before the HAVING clause